# Get Google to index new URLs after migrating to Godaddy Simple Website Builder which doesn't support redirects

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, 404, godaddy

I recently updated a website for my company from its extremely outdated design (last edited in 2009). After the update, when you click on the page in the google search it says that there is nothing there. I understand why this is happening.  The old website's home page was /home/ but the new website's home page is just /.  I understand that the urls for the home pages are different and this is not my issue.

I want to know how to get the link on google changed. I am using the simple website builder on godaddy.com so I cannot change the naming structure.  According to godaddy, I submitted the site map to google.  In the google search console, it shows that google has crawled my website twice already, but has omitted crawling the index page. How do I get this fixed, because my company is loosing business from not getting people to click on their website?  We are currently the top organic search result when searching key words.

Comment: You'd need to do a [301](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/301-redirects) redirect from `/home` to the root directory. Unfortunately it doesn't look like GoDaddy's website builder has the functionality to do redirects according to [this](https://www.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Website-Builders/Website-Builder-Redirects/td-p/123413). Contact GoDaddy's support to see if they can add one for you.